# Pytables. How to get iterate over unique values?

Tags: python, pytables

I have a dataset in Pytables, which looks something like

```
class myData(IsDescription):
    date = StringCol(16)
    item = Int32Col()
```

I have multiple items per same date, for example:

```
'2010-01-01', 5
'2010-01-01', 6
'2010-01-02', 7
'2010-01-02', 8
```

Is there a way to iterate over unique dates and then over items in the date? I mean something like

```
for date in DATE
    print date
     for ITEM
         print item
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not familiar with the inner-workings of Pytables (so this may not be in-line with what you are looking for), but the `groupby` function in the `itertools` module is very useful in these types of situations (note the sorting step below - this is important in this case in order to get `groupby` to group all items with the same date. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for more info.):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: from operator import attrgetter

In [3]: class myData(object):
    def __init__(self, date, item):
        self.date = date
        self.item = item
   ...:         

In [4]: l = [myData('2012-01-01', 'thing'), myData('2012-01-01', 'another thing'), myData('2013-01-01', 'and another')]

In [5]: l_sorted = sorted(l, key=attrgetter('date'))

In [6]: for date, my_objects in groupby(l_sorted, key=attrgetter('date')):
   ...:     print date
   ...:     for obj in my_objects:
   ...:         print obj.item
   ...:         
2012-01-01
thing
another thing
2013-01-01
and another
```

The basic pattern here is to get a list/container that holds the objects you want to group. You then sort that list based by the attribute by which we will later be grouping (in this case, `date`). You then pass that sorted list to the `groupby` function, which will emit two values in each iteration - a `key` that represents the value by which you grouped (so here it will be the `date` of each group) and a `group` iterator that contains all of your objects that share that same `date` key. You can then iterate through that group, pulling out the `item` attribute of each object.

Comment: This seems like the correct way if I had the data in class, but in pytables it is stored as ndarray, i.e I can access data[:]['date'] but not data[5].date (And sorted/groupby don't work)

Comment: Oh. The solution is to use itemgetter and not attrgetter. Thank you!